# Should I split a ruby single-line if statement into multi-line if statement because the line is long?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I have a ruby single-line statement that is very long, about 200 characters. According to a [ruby style guide](https://github.com/github/rubocop-github/blob/master/STYLEGUIDE.md), single-line if statement is favored here because the body is single-line.

```
address = Module::InnerModule::Class.new(long_address) if Module::Class.new(long_address).is_good?
```

But, 200 characters is way over the usual threshold for line length (which is usually 120 at most). Should I split the if statement into a multi-line statement in order to reduce the line length (or should I just accept that the line is long)?

```
if Module::Class.new(long_address).is_good? 
  address = Module::InnerModule::Class.new(long_address)
```

Also, what happens if the line is still very long after splitting? What is the best practice here? I'm new to Ruby, so I would appreciate any advice on the best practice here.

Comment: You are working with it, so you can judge best how it is easiest to read for you. Reformat it, until it looks fine for you.

Comment: @user1934428 I understand the subjectivity involved, but there are other people working on the same project. Wouldn't it be better to understand what the Ruby community thinks about this (instead of using just my individual opinion)?

Comment: Perhaps, but [so] discourages discussions about questions, which depend on the personal opinion of the individuals, perhaps because this leeds to endless discussions. Some people dislike the use of an `if` added to a statement altogether, others use a font so that they can easily see lines of length 300 characters, I prefer lines to be not more than 72 characters long  - how can you expect that this can be reasonably discussed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style questions aside, if you want to maintain your current semantics, you can break lines at certain keywords and operators without escaping newlines with backslashes. For example:

```
address =
  Module::InnerModule::Class.new(long_address) if
    Module::Class.new(long_address).is_good?
```

Otherwise, change your semantics or refactor your code to fit your desired line length and chosen style. Questions about *how* to split lines are answerable, but the “best” way to split, indent, or refactor are largely subjective, and mostly amount to a combination of readability and intent.